# Any way to trigger a new activity to be opened from a custom capacitor plugin

Tags: capacitor

Is there any way to trigger a new activity to be opened from a custom `Capacitor` plugin? I'm using [plaid-link-android](https://github.com/plaid/plaid-link-android/blob/master/app/src/main/java/com/plaid/linksample/MainActivityJava.java#L33) to open a new `Plaid` link. And since I want this to be triggered when a button is clicked in my app, I was thinking I would need a custom plugin to trigger it. But the problem is, I can't use the `registerForActivityResult` method within the plugin class because it isn't an Android activity. Not only do I need to be able to `launch` this new activity from the plugin, but I also need that plugin method to be able to read the result from the `ActivityResultCallback` somehow.

Does anybody have any ideas?

Comment: Did you ever fix this?

Comment: Check out the official documentation which has some example code: https://capacitorjs.com/docs/plugins/android#intents-with-results